# Can I get the formatted text size using ReportLab in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab, text-formatting

Is it possible to get the size/extents of rendered text in reportLab?

I need to calculate some positions relative to other elements on the page.

The flowable system isn't want I'm looking for. I don't mind using it to get the sizes if necessary, but it's not appropriate for my overall layout. *I tried creating a `Paragraph` an calling `wrap` but it returns the available width always, not the measured extends.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may get the width of a rendered text with `stringWidth`:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth
width = stringWidth(text, font_name, font_size)
```

Line spacing gives you the height of a line of text.